# librosa sound wav file shape changed the original shape to random shape

Tags: scipy, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, librosa

I'm currently working on voice recognition deep learning project. 
I need augment my current data with shift sound file or stretched it
but the problem is shape is changing during the augmentation process

```
  y, sr = librosa.load(os.path.join(train_data_path, label, fname))
  librosa.output.write_wav('./input/train_test2/'+label+'/10000'+fname  ,y,sr)
```

eventhough I did not change anything it change the shape. 
let say I originally have the shape with (99,81,1) but after I changed it it changed to (77,81,1) or something else

but the problem is that When I was using the keras for classification

```
inp = Input(shape=input_shape)
norm_inp = BatchNormalization()(inp)
img_1 = Convolution2D(8, kernel_size=2, activation=activations.relu)(norm_inp)
img_1 = Convolution2D(8, kernel_size=2, activation=activations.relu)(img_1)
img_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(img_1)
img_1 = Dropout(rate=0.2)(img_1)
```

different input_shape is  not  working for keras.
I'm not even sure its possible to keep the original shape after I modify the wav file

1. is it possible to keep the original shape?
2. if its not possible is it possible to change it  to the original file shape?
3. what other solution u suggest?

===========================================
the shape change after I do the log_spectrogram

```
def log_specgram(audio, sample_rate, window_size=20,
                 step_size=10, eps=1e-10):
    nperseg = int(round(window_size * sample_rate / 1e3))
    noverlap = int(round(step_size * sample_rate / 1e3))
    freqs, times, spec = signal.spectrogram(audio,
                                    fs=sample_rate,
                                    window='hann',
                                    nperseg=nperseg,
                                    noverlap=noverlap,
                                    detrend=False)
    return freqs, times, np.log(spec.T.astype(np.float32) + eps)
```

this np.log(spec.T.astype(np.float32) + eps) 's shape is different

=============================================================
original file

```
sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read('./input/train/audio/eight/012c8314_nohash_1.wav')
print(sample_rate , sample_rate_test)
new_sample_rate = 8000
resampled = signal.resample(samples, int(new_sample_rate / sample_rate * samples.shape[0]))
print(resampled2.shape)
_, _, specgram = log_specgram(resampled, sample_rate=new_sample_rate)
print("specgramshape->", specgram.shape)
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y =samples, sr =sample_rate, n_mels=128, fmax = 8000  )    
print("S->", S.shape)

librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max), y_axis = 'mel' , fmax = 8000, x_axis='time')


16000 22050
(5804,)
specgramshape-> (99, 81)
S-> (128, 32)
```

===============================================================

after used

```
y = librosa.resample(y,sr,16000)
librosa.output.write_wav('./input/train_test/'+label+'/10000'+fname  ,y,sr)

(16000,) (16000,)
(5804,)
specgramshape-> (71, 81)
S-> (128, 32)
```

=====================================================================

Comment: What do your shapes mean? Commonly an audio signal has shape (N_samples, N_channels). What do you mean by "augment [...] data with shift sound"? How do you change the audio? Your snippet shows only that you load a file and then save it to another path. The NN part of your question is completely irrelevant to your problem. Tagging this with NN tags is misleading, since NN is not the problem here.

Comment: I modify the question

Comment: "this np.log(...) 's shape is different"; different than what?

Comment: If get that right you problem is that the mel-spec has different shape then the log-spec, right?. Well, thats because you calc the log-spec on a resampled version of `samples` and the mel-spec on the original `samples`. However, `resampled` is much shorter than `samples`, hence the difference in output.

Comment: freqs, times, spec = signal.spectrogram(audio,
                                    fs=sample_rate,
                                    window='hann',
                                    nperseg=nperseg,
                                    noverlap=noverlap,
                                    detrend=False)

Comment: in this step different shape spitting out . is there way to make it same shape?

Comment: Ok I'll stop right here, because I think the problem is that you lack some signal processing basics.